# Cannot convert value of type '[NSLayoutConstraint]' to expected argument type 'NSLayoutConstraint'

Tags: swift, constraints, ios-autolayout

**I am using Xcode 9 beta 5 .I pragmatically added the contrarian**

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H: |-16-[v0]-16-|" , options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":thumbnailImageView]))

addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V: |-16-[v0]-16-|" , options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0":thumbnailImageView]))
```

**I am getting error:**

> Cannot convert value of type '[NSLayoutConstraint]' to expected argument type 'NSLayoutConstraint'

**Error Image**

[image: Screen Shot]

How to remove this error?

Comment: You pass a list where a single instance is required.

Comment: how to remove this error ?

Comment: by the way, you can use `[]` instead of `NSLayoutFormatOptions()`.

Comment: ...or you can leave off `options: []` altogether because that is the default value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat:options:metrics:views)` returns an array of constraints, and not just a single constraint.

Since iOS8, it is recommended to *activate* constraints instead of adding them to a view.  For a single constraint, you can just set its `isActive` property to `true`, and iOS will add that constraint to the proper view to active it.

For multiple constraints, use `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` to activate the constraints instead of adding them to the view:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-16-|", metrics: nil, views: ["v0":thumbnailImageView]))
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-16-[v0]-16-|", metrics: nil, views: ["v0":thumbnailImageView]))
```

Comment: I support this answers... by setting isActive = true, if you add them, it will be activated when neccesary... otherwise you might face issues, like the view is not in hierarchy, etc...

Comment: Program does not successfully complete execution . Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. Program stops execution and caught in thread ..form this link you can download program that stops execution and caught in thread ..https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnYkk0elRYUElmcjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you add thumbnailView as a subview of another view?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Expected a view 
H: |-16-[v0]-16-|

Comment: There's a problem with your format strings.  Try getting rid of the space and add a final dash before the end horizontal bar:  `"H:|-16-[v0]-16-|"` and `"V:|-16-[v0]-16-|"`.

Comment: in spite of this "H:|-16-[v0]-16-|" and "V:|-16-[v0]-16-|" format program is still crashing

Comment: Did you get rid of the space, because you didn't in your edited question.

Comment: I verified that your constraint strings will work if you get rid of the space and add the `-`.

Answer (score 7):

`UIView` has two methods to add constraints:

- `func addConstraint(_ constraint: NSLayoutConstraint)`

  which expects a **single** `NSLayoutConstraint`and
- `func addConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])`

  which expects an **array** of `NSLayoutConstraint` instances

Just use the appropriate API

Comment: Note that the definition of addConstraints has the comment: *This method will be deprecated in a future release and should be avoided.  Instead use +[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:]*

Answer (score 5):

You have to use 'addConstraints' not 'addConstraint'

Comment: holy mother.. quite 20 minutes i try to figure it out. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, in my case I was using:

```
view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|[\(label)]|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: viewsDictionary
    )
)
```

And had the same problem. You should use addConstraints(with "s"):

```
view.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|[\(label)]|",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: viewsDictionary
        )
    )
```